# Time Object conversion to float in Python

Tags: python

I have a column with the time formated as "2021/03/19 00:30:00+00" in a CSV file. I want to convert the time format to float in python. I tried DateTime functions but I was not successful. I appreciate any guidance

Comment: Could you show what you tried and why it didn't  work?

Answer (score 1):

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
parse("2021/03/19 00:30:00+00").timestamp()
```

Result:

```
1616113800.0
```

You can read about `dateutil` [here](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Comment: There is no need to import `datetime` to use `dateutil`.  NB to the op that `dateutil` is a 3rd-party package (albeit a very useful one).

Comment: @2e0byo Thanks, copy-paste error.

Comment: The important part of this answer is `timestamp`, not `dateutil`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `datetime` form the standard library you can control the string format using the directives, `%character`, see for [details](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

To create a `datetime` object the string should be well-formatted, here two ways to achieve this.

Problem of `"2021/03/19 00:30:00+00"`: the timezone `+00` is not valid

**Custom formatting** method:

the `%z` utc offset timezone directive has to be of the form `±HHMM[SS[.ffffff]]`, so just append `'00'`

```
import datetime

dt_str = "2021/03/19 00:30:00+00"
dt_str += '00' # valid UTC time zone format (does NOT affect the time)
dt_format = '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S%z'
dt_float = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt_str, dt_format).timestamp()
print(dt_float)

# 1616113800.0
```

**To iso-formatting** method:

The format of an iso-formatted string should be:

`YYYY-MM-DD[*HH[:MM[:SS[.fff[fff]]]][+HH:MM[:SS[.ffffff]]]]`

- to a valid utc offset timezone a `':00'` should be appended
- replace `/` --> `-` in the date

```
dt_string = "2021/03/19 00:30:00+00" + ":00" 
dt_iso_string = dt_string.replace('/', '-')
dt_float = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(dt_iso_string).timestamp()
```

Comment: Wait … the `+0` is a timezone specification, not deciseconds …